# I cant see the UTM i create in my google analytics funnel

Tags: google-analytics, utm

I've created a UTM link in the UTM site https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/campaign-url-builder/

I entered "TEST" on source & Medium to see if i can follow it around in my google analytics.

but for some reason my GA won"t show it anywhere. Not in acquisition, behavior or goals

i'd love to know if theres a way to follow my UTMs directly and where GA puts them.

Answer (score 0):

You can find it in source / medium report. In Channel Grouping you will find it in (Other) channel.